# Design related bug

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

Today morning I see design related bug in user sections.

fonts and color not looks good and also you feel buggy when you hover tabs.

[image]

Comment: now you have seeing  something?

Comment: @AmitBera yes issue is still there https://magento.stackexchange.com/users

Comment: aah, i see. We will look on it. Donot thought  it is an issue. Let me check

Comment: Summoning @Hynes. Maybe he can help.

Comment: okay thanks @Marius

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala  Definitely a bug. Thanks for bringing it to our attention. I'll ask around and make sure we get this fixed today or tomorrow.

Comment: sure, thank you @Hynes for your support

Comment: @Hynes please check in meta site also you cannot able to read anchor text in hover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your patience. This is a new style being rolled out on Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network soon. Unfortunately, as you saw, there are a few errors still, so this change has been reverted.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a but or a new design feature.
Either way.... this does not happen only on the magento website.
Took a look on other websites like

- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users
- https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users

and they look similar.

Comment: Hello , if you see our meta site then you can't read text when you hover it, and also in main site when you hover the background changes twice that's not look good

Comment: Oh yeah...I think it's because the colors. You are right.